# In Qt Framework based Python desktop application , is it possible to give a internally created CSV save as or select location to save option?

Tags: python, qt, csv

I am creating a csv file while clicking a button, now after the csv creation completed I want to give user save the CSV option in your desired location. Is it possible in Qt framework based desktop application in python? Thanks .

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use this class:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qfiledialog.html (Qt 4.8)

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html (Qt 5.0)